# Concourse Slack alert

Tags: concourse

I have written a bash script it process some data and puts in one file. My intention is to give slack alert if there is content in that file if not it should not give the alert. Is there a way to do it? In Concourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of the Concourse community's open source resource types. There's a list [here](https://resource-types.concourse-ci.org). There is a slack resource listed on that page, but I use the one here (not included in the list above because it has not been added by the authors) https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/slack-notification-resource.

That will give you the ability to add a `put` step in your job plan to send a slack resource. As for the logic of your original ask, you can use `try` and `on_success`. Your task might look something like this:

```
- try:
    task: do-a-thing 
    config:
      platform: linux

      image_resource:
      type: registry-image
      source:
          repository: YOUR_TASK_IMAGE
          tag: latest

      inputs:
      - name: some-input    
      params:
        FILE: some-file

      run:
        path: /bin/sh
        args:
        - -ec
        - |
          [ ! -z `cat some-input/${FILE}` ]
    on_success:
      put: slack
      params:
        <your slack resource put params go here>
```

The `on_success` part will run if the code defined in the task's `run` section returns 0. The script listed there just checks to see if there are more than zero bytes in the file. Because the task is wrapped in a `try` step, regardless of whether or not the task succeeds (and hence, sends you a message), the step will succeed and move to the next step in the plan.

Comment: I need some more help on this. Actually  -z check's if it has empty string or not. I have tested locally if there is a content it returns  1 if no content it returns 0. As you have mentioned that it give the alert only if it returns 0. If my understanding is correct

Comment: `[ -z STRING ]` returns 0 if the string in question is empty, that's correct. I put a `!` to negate that, so this will return 0 if `some-input/${FILE}` exists and is not empty (`cat` would fail if the file did not exist). When that script returns 0, the task has completed successfully and its `on_success` handler is run.